# How to get the input word as output word in neural network

Tags: recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to get the input word as output word with LSTM(copy a word). For that, I have seen some snippets. In those examples, I observed that we need to convert characters of a word into integers. But Those examples were written to predict the next characters.

an example of what I am trying

`input_word = 'algebra'
pass the input_word through some network
output_word = 'algebra'`

This is the link I was tried
(https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-character-based-neural-language-model-keras/).

Any Idea or links about the problem is helpful.

Comment: How about a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Try word2vec algorithm or Glove

Comment: @raddy How word2vec will help in this case. But I am trying to get the input word as output using LSTM(LongShort term memory).